# Auto associate an elastic ip to a ec2 instance started by ecs task

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-ip, amazon-ecs

There is a way to auto associate an elasticip to an ec2 instance that was started by an ecs task?
I'm trying to create a mongodb cluster with replicaset (3 nodes) and I would like to "plug" a new ec2 instance to my cluster automatically when an ecs task start new instances.

Comment: I found this [repo](https://github.com/skymill/aws-ec2-assign-elastic-ip) but I'm in a doubt if is the better way to do that and if I can do this using ECS

Comment: I found this [link](http://serverfault.com/questions/544525/associate-elastic-ip-automatically-to-a-amazon-ec2-instance-when-the-instance-st?rq=1#answer-544526) too, but again I'm not sure if this is the way that I should follow